# Disabling Delete button in UITableView temporarily

Tags: ios, uitableview

The Delete button on the app I'm working on makes a server call when tapped.

However while we are waiting for the server to respond, I am able click the Delete button multiple times, and hence sending out multiple server request.

I am looking at solution where I want to disable the Delete button until I hear back from the server. Is this possible? Or is there another graceful solution for this? Or am I doing something wrong in the first place.

Thanks!

Comment: Disable the button the first time it is tapped. Enable it again when ready.

Comment: I guess I should have phrased this question better. It was about how to disable/enable it, not whether or not to. How do I access the delete button of the UITableView? There seems to be no deleteButton in UITableView. I can't seem to find it in the Apple docs either.

Comment: Oh, you are talking about the delete button in the cell? Which one? The little red circle or the big red Delete confirmation button?

Comment: The big delete confirmation button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that when you show the Delete confirmation button in a table cell, and then the user taps the button, you handle the deletion in the usual `commitEditingStyle` delegate method.

But it also sounds like you kick off a server request and while it is executing, the Delete button is still in view. This implies that you don't actually delete the row until the server request is complete.

If this is the case then what you should do in your `commitEditingStyle` method is to immediately reload the row being deleted. This will remove the delete button. Then kick off the server request. Once the server request is done, you then update your data source as appropriate and then delete the row or reload the table or section as needed.

It might be nice to add a little activity indicator to cell letting the user know the row is being processed. You may also want to prevent the user from swiping on the row again while the server request is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method when tapped first time:

```
[deleteButton setEnabled:NO];
```

Then enable it when you receive a response from the server.

Comment: Better yet, use `deleteButton.enabled = NO`. Disabling the button will update its appearance properly. Your approach won't change the appearance of the button.

Comment: This is for the delete button already included in the UITableViewCell, which is not directly accessible.